# SSL Certificate - x.509 File from NamesCheap - How to install on ReactJS ( On Suze Linux )

Tags: reactjs, linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, opensuse

As the title is self explanatory , I want to install "SSL Certificate - x.509 File from NamesCheap on ReactJS ( On Suze Linux )"

Most of the online websites ask to create a .pem and .crt file.

I was wondering what is the need of these two when I have the certificate itself.

How can I use this on reactJS.